# CentOS 6 does not show any desktop icons or anything in the panel

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos

I was using CentOS 6 in VirtualBox fine for a couple of days.  Now, when I login via the GUI user prompt, all I get is the background screen, no icons, no menubar, nothing.  I am not terribly familiar with UNIX, but have used it in the past.  That being said, if you need me to locate error messages to help diagnose this, please be specific as to where to locate files or specific commands that you would like me to execute, if possible.  I have gotten to the GRUB prompt, but don't know what to do from there.

I am reposting this question as the one for CentOS 5 had no visible answers.

Comment: I realized that I could login as root from the GUI prompt.  When I did, everything worked as expected.  This let me know that there was a problem with the user account.  

So, as root, I disabled the scripts in the user .cshrc.  Once the scripts were disabled, I logged into the user account.  Everything came up as expected.

Now, I just need to debug the scripts that were being run via the .cshrc.

Answer (score 0):

At the screen with nothing on it, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (Or possibly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), which should take you to a login console.  Login with your credentials, then run 'sudo dmesg > dmesg.out'.  Look through dmesg.out for errors related to gnome and post any you find here...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have edited my question with the solution I found, since I am disallowed from answering my own question for 8 hours.